# IIS rewrite problem - how-to rewrite initial URL without path to URL with path

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I would like add a "rewrite" rule on my IIS8

from : site1.mydomain.com/{R:1}
to : site2.anotherdomain.com/onelevelpath/{R:1}

actually, my rule is :

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://technofuturtic.wixsite.com/tftic-helpdesk-it/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

result give : http://site1.mydomain.com/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath/onelevelpath with error "request exceed maxUrlLenght"

Of course, I understand de problem... but I don't find de correct solution ?

- change the pattern ?
- add a condition ?

Someone could help me ?

Thank you.

E.

Comment: Hi @DingPeng. an thank you for your answer. No, problem isn't solved. On my Site, site1.mydomain.com is the binding. therfore you can't use it in the "Input data to test". And /{R:1} (or {R:0}, I think) is mandatory... because there is also path and sub-path to be add to URL rewrited: site1.mydomain.com/***/***/*** to : site2.anotherdomain.com/onelevelpath/***/***/***

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is a problem with your URL Rewrite Rule:

[image]

You can see that {R:1} at this time is site1.mydomain.com/{R:1}.

**{R:1} has other meanings in URL Rewrite, for more information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules).**

**My suggestion is to avoid {R:1} in the URL, which will cause IIS to confuse the value of {R:1}.**

Another point to note is that if you rewrite from one domain to another, you need to use redirection.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to rewrite site1.mydomain.com/***/***/*** to site2.anotherdomain.com/onelevelpath/***/***/***, you can use the following URL Rewrite Rule:

```
   <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site1.mydomain.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://site2.anotherdomain.com/onelevelpath/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: Dear Ding-Peng,

Your solution isn't totally the one expected (I would like a rewrite, not a redirect).. But I will take your proposal. that's working and this is the main. Thank you.